# Filter query error in QGIS2.4 or 2.6

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, query, filter

I get this error when undertaking in query in QGIS2.4 or QGIS2.6:

An error occurred when executing the query.
The data provider said:
OGR[3] error 1: Unrecognised field name Fire.isochrones_2002_BigDesert_21122002.OBJECTID.

All my field names are less than or equal to 8 characters.

Anyone got any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Here, "Fire.isochrones_2002_BigDesert_21122002.OBJECTID" is interpreted as a single field name. What are the different attributes? : Fire, isochrones_2002, OBJECTID? The problem is probably coming from the dots in the field name.

Comment: I had same error for ESRI file with a dot in the name. It worked after rename the datafiles. This bug is still present in QGIS2.8. Bug was reported in ogr in 2014 (https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5379), marked as corrected 3 months later, but is still an issue in QGIS to date.